# Pass Lists to MVC controller Action using POSTMan chrome extention

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api

I am using Postman Chrome extension to test my MVC service API.

The model that I pass to the controller looks as follows:

```
public class ActivateBenefitRequestModel
{
    public int BenefitID { get; set; }
    public int MemberID { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public List<AdditionalBenefitField> BenefitAdditionalFields { get; set; } 
}
```

with

```
public class AdditionalBenefitField
{
    public int BenefitFieldId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

How should I go about passing in the BenefitAdditionalFields List ?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I got it and it's pretty easy:

Just set separate text values in your form data in the PostMan extention

```
BenefitAdditionalFields[0].BenefitFieldId
BenefitAdditionalFields[0].Value
BenefitAdditionalFields[1].BenefitFieldId
BenefitAdditionalFields[1].Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all you're doing is building a POST request string (not familiar with the extension), I believe you can just format your request to specify individual list elements indexed with URL-encoded square brackets:

```
...&AdditionalBenefitFields%5B0%5D.BenefitFieldId=1&AdditionalBenefitFields%5B0%5D.Value=Foo
&AdditionalBenefitFields%5B1%5D.BenefitFieldId=2&AdditionalBenefitFields%5B1%5D.Value=Bar&...
```

This is how a POST request for a list of complex types looks in one of our MVC3 projects and I'm pretty sure we don't do anything special with it.